# How to run a gatling test from a java code and pass the url of test in parameters of simulation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gatling, scala-gatling

I want to be able to pass parameters to a Gatling Simulation from a java code and specially the url of test. I use Gatling with maven method. Someone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be:
for example, i need to pass the URL under the test http://127.0.0.1:5000

```
 mvn clean gatling:test -Dfoo="http://127.0.0.1:5000"
```

to pick this variable in scala code:

```
val foo_url = System.getProperty("foo")
```

and to utilize this foo_url in simulation:

```
val httpProtocol = http
    //.baseUrl("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
    .baseUrl(foo_url)
```

Comment: may I know the error you have received? and also a code snippet on how your code looks if possible.

Comment: Thanks it work now my mistake is making the URL between ' ' and not " "